# How to float text to the right for Angular UI Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I want to float the countdown timer text for an `alert` element which will auto-close towards **the right side** of a Angular UI Bootstrap's [alert](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

When I use something super simplistic like `class="pull-right"`, it looks quite ugly as it loses its alignment with the rest of the message.
[image]
Any hint or ideas for styling it properly?

### Edit # 1

When using rows/columns, it doesn't end up looking right:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">{{alert.msg}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">({{countdownInMilliSeconds/1000}})</div>
        </div>
    </alert>
</div>
```

Here down how it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please provide your HTML/CSS code, even better if you can create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an inline block `<span>` for your count down timer just after the alert message with class `pull-right` and it should fit in what you exactelly need:

```html
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}<span class="pull-right">({{countdownInMilliSeconds/1000}})</span></alert>
  <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
```

***[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tmarwen/ty4oa1xm/2/)***

Comment: Yup `span` or `div` either one works fine as long as the first element doesn't have anything around it.

Comment: Yes it is an inline element so it means the same, but you shoul always use semantic templates.
By the way, you should never add an answer as a comment to the OP so you would better delete it before it gets downvoted by some strict guys ;)

Comment: Well, it wasn't just a comment, it was a real answer (see timestamp) which was shortly followed by more feedback from the community :) But yeah I want to delete it and the time has passed.

Comment: Nice, I thought you wanted only to react for this issue, but since it is an answer It sounds fair enough and I will even upvote it ;)

Answer (score 5):

Refer this [Offset Columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) in [bootsrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and it solves your issue.

Try this

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">({{countdownInMilliSeconds/1000}})</div>
</div>
```

instead of

```
<div style="float: right">({{countdownInMilliSeconds/1000}})</div>
```

Comment: I provided feedback upstairs as update # 1 because I could only attach an image in the question itself.

Comment: There is one easy method check angular documentation "spaces-between-center"

Answer (score 1):

I had started with:

`<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">
  {{alert.msg}}
</alert>`

And added the countdown timer like so:

`<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">
  <div>{{alert.msg}}</div>
  <div style="float: right">({{countdownInMilliSeconds/1000}})</div>
</alert>`

But I could apparently do without the first `div`, in order to get the proper alignment:

`<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">
  {{alert.msg}}
  <div style="float: right">({{countdownInMilliSeconds/1000}})</div>
</alert>`

Comment: Try this "<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">({{countdownInMilliSeconds/1000}})</div>" instead of  <div style="float: right">({{countdownInMilliSeconds/1000}})</div>